# Is nltest output not valid to use with new-object?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

when running the nltest command "nltest /dsgetdc:contoso.com", I get the following output:

DC: \DC1.contoso.com
Address: \192.168.0.100
Dom Guid: 1234567a-abc1-4d66-a421-153f0116d8c7
Dom Name: contoso.com
Forest Name: contoso.com
DC Site Name: New York
Our Site Name: New York
Flags: PDC GC DS LDAP KDC TIMESERV....etc..

What I'm trying to do is capture the output of the DC and eventually the Address fields.  I tried the following but it doesn't seem to like it:

```
$svc=nltest /dsgetdc:contoso.com 
$obj=new-object psobject -property {DC=$svc.DC}
```

> New-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'Property'. Cannot convert the
>   "DC=$svc.DC" value of type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock"
>   to type "System.Collections.IDictionary". At line:1 char:36
>   + $obj=new-object psobject -property {DC=$svc.DC}
>   +                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

So obviously i'm making the call incorrectly/using the command incorrectly.  Should I even use new-object for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briantist has a great answer detailing the issues with how you are treating the output of `nltest`. Since the output from `nltest` is already well formatted with name:value I propose the use of [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849900.aspx).

```powershell
$results = ((nltest /dsgetdc:contoso.com) -replace ":","=" | 
    Where-Object{$_ -match "="}) -join "`r`n" | 
    ConvertFrom-StringData
new-object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $results
```

We use `-replace ":","="` to convert all the colons to equal signs. Then we filter out and lines that do not have an equal sign. That is to remove any status message like "The command completed successfully". `ConvertFrom-StringData` expects a single string so we join the lines with new lines to make that single string. `ConvertFrom-StringData` makes a hashtable that we store in `$results`.

Then, just like your question and [briantists answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29978622/3829407), we make a `PsCustomObject`. The output would look like the following.

```
Dc Site Name  : CON
Our Site Name : CON
DC            : \DCCONTOSO.COM
Flags         : GC DS LDAP KDC TIMESERV WRITABLE DNS_DC DNS_DOMAIN DNS_FOREST CLOSE_SITE FULL_SECRET WS
Address       : \1254.885.1.478
Dom Name      : CONTOSO.COM
Dom Guid      : 0a3be324-f399-4b44-a3f1-b9c5aa6e7c5b
Forest Name   : CONTOSO.COM
```

Just save the results of the object creation into a variable then you can access the properties like you would any object in PowerShell.

Comment: Very cool, +1. I didn't realize that `ConvertFrom-StringData` existed actually. I was getting it confused with `ConvertFrom-String` in PowerShell 5.0 (hope you don't mind, I edited your answer since it had a few instances of the latter).

Comment: @briantist No its perfectly ok. My answer was misleading otherwise

Comment: Thanks gents.  Much appreciated.  Always a learning day for me when it comes to PS.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you aren't using it properly (not quite).

`New-Object -Property` expects a `[hashtable]`. You're passing it `{}` which indicates a `[scriptblock]`. You would need to use a `@{}` to indicate a hash.

However, the output from that command is just a string with newlines, and you can't just put that directly into `@{}` to make a hashtable.

So here's some code that could do that for you:

```powershell
$svc=nltest /dsgetdc:contoso.com 

$h = @{}

$svc -split '\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^(?<key>[^:]+):\s+(?<value>.+)$') {
        $h[$Matches['key']] = $Matches['value']
    }
}

$obj = New-Object PSObject -Property $h
```

We're splitting the output based on newlines, then for each line, doing a regular expression match and pulling out the key and value, and adding it to the hash, then using that in the call to `New-Object`.