# Regex in powershell does not work as expected

Tags: regex, powershell

I store the output of a defragmentation analysis in a variable, then I try to match a pattern to retrieve a number.

In [this following online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/oD0zT3/2), it works fine but in powershell, `String -match $pattern` returns false.

My code:

```
$result = Defrag C: /A /V | Out-String
echo $result
$pattern = "fragmenté[^.0-9]*([0-9]+)%"
$result -match $pattern
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Suspect you may be dealing with line break issues...might check something like piping the result to a file, then using Get-Content on the file, then Out-String to purge the breaks. Not sure on syntax off the top of my head, sorry :)

Comment: I just did exactly as you said, it still doesn't work. I also tried to cast to a string instead of using `Out-String` to remove every line breaks, and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Okay, there is also an explicit multiline modifier for PowerShell regexps..something like [regex]::matches($str, "fragmente[^.0-9]*([0-9]+)%", "MultiLine")..again sorry for rough syntax, just can't test at the moment

Comment: I have to convert the string to english for me but it is working just fine. I'm not sure but wonder if the accents are the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that `$result` contains the text you expect while this is being run. Are you running this from an elevated console?

Comment: On my system, there's a whitespace between the number and %. Could you please provide the output of defrag? Btw.: regex101 has no .net flavored regex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had no issue with your code. I just needed to change the match to support my English output. It is possible that [Wolfgang Kluge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2693792/wolfgang-kluge) is onto something about the whitespace. However if your output *actually* matches what you have in the regex tester than i'm not sure what this issue you are having.

For fun I propose this update to your code. This uses [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849900.aspx). I explain the code more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29980012/3829407).

```powershell
$defrag = Defrag C: /A /V | out-string
$hash = (($defrag -split "`r`n" | Where-Object{$_ -match "="}) -join "`r`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData)
$result = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $hash

$result."Quantité totale d'espace fragmenté"
```

This is of course assuming that your PowerShell is perfectly OK with the accents in the words. On my ISE 3.0 that above code works.

Again... your code was working just fine for me in your question. I also don't think the `Out-String` is *required*. I still get positive output. With `Out-String` I get extra output that includes the entire matched line. Else I just get a boolean. In both (using the following code) I still get a result.

```powershell
$result = Defrag C: /A /V #| Out-String
$pattern = "fragmented space[^.0-9]*([0-9]+)%"
$result -match $pattern
$Matches[1]
```

`-match` works as an array operator which changes how `$result` is treated. With `Out-String` `$result` is a `System.String` and without it you get `System.Object`

**False Theory**

The only way I can get the match to be `False` is if I am not running PowerShell as an administrator. That is important because if not you will get a message

> The disk defragmenter cannot start because you have insufficient priveleges to perform this operation. (0x89000024)

Comment: Well, it seems like the accent were the issue. I tried with another word w/o accents and it work. How should I setup my powershell to support accents then?

Comment: @LoveMetal Are you using console or ISE and what version of PS are you running?

Comment: Powershell console in admin mode, version 4

Comment: Console powershell as admin, version 4